# Beyondcode Laravel mailbox with postmark returns HTTP status code of 405

Tags: laravel-10, http-status-code-405, laravel-mail, postmark, inbound

I trying to use Postmark for Laravel Mailbox for catch mails, but it returns a HTTP status code of 405 when using the below webhook url,

Inbound Webhook : https://laravel-mailbox:testing@finding.lk/laravel-mailbox/postmark

[image]

If I add a "/" sign at the end of URL it returns a status code with 200. like below,

Inbound Webhook : https://laravel-mailbox:testing@finding.lk/laravel-mailbox/postmark/

[image]

but it not catching any mails from Postmark.

Here is the my mailbox.php,

```
<?php
return [

/*
 * The driver to use when listening for incoming emails.
 * It defaults to the mail driver that you are using.
 *
 * Supported drivers: "log", "mailgun", "sendgrid", "postmark"
 */
'driver' => 'postmark',

/*
 * The model class to use when converting an incoming email to a message.
 * It must extend the default model class
 */
'model' => \BeyondCode\Mailbox\InboundEmail::class,

/*
 * The path for driver specific routes. This is where
 * you need to point your driver specific callbacks
 * to.
 *
 * For example: /laravel-mailbox/sendgrid/
 */
'path' => 'laravel-mailbox/postmark/',

/*
 * The amount of days that incoming emails should be stored in your
 * application. You can use the cleanup artisan command to
 * delete all older inbound emails on a regular basis.
 * Set to INF to disable the cleanup artisan command.
 */
'store_incoming_emails_for_days' => 7,

/*
 * By default, this package only stores incoming email messages
 * when they match one of your mailboxes. To store all incoming
 * messages, modify this value.
 */
'only_store_matching_emails' => true,

/*
 * Some services do not have their own authentication methods to
 * verify the incoming request. For these services, you need
 * to use this username and password combination for HTTP
 * basic authentication.
 *
 * See the driver specific documentation if it applies to your
 * driver.
 */
'basic_auth' => [
    'username' => 'laravel-mailbox',
    'password' => 'testing',
],

/*
 * Third party service configuration.
 */
'services' => [

    'postmark' => [
        'key' => '2d1cf750-050c-484f-857a-d819c4beafc5',
    ],

],
```

];

and the AppServiceProvider.php,

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Cashier\Cashier;
use App\Models\Tenant;
use App\Models\MailboxInboundEmails;
use App\Models\Subscription;
use BeyondCode\Mailbox\InboundEmail;
use BeyondCode\Mailbox\Facades\Mailbox;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

public function register(): void
{
    
}


public function boot(): void
{
    Cashier::useCustomerModel(Tenant::class);
    Cashier::useSubscriptionModel(Subscription::class);

    Mailbox::catchAll(static function(InboundEmail $email) {
        // Handle the incoming email
        Log::info('#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#');
        Log::info($email);
        Log::info('#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#');
    });
 }
```

}

Please help me with this code. Thank you.